# Jest tests show Object is possibly 'null' errors

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, jestjs

I have some tests cases which are testing mongoose Models. But on running them with Jest (typescript code) I get many running errors :

> error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

Example code (error is on line 3) :

```
const user = await User.findById("id_test");
expect(user).toBeDefined();
expect(user.password).not.toBe("older_password");
```

Yes my user can be null, but it can be a unprecise test case but certainly not a blocking error...

How can I make my test pass ? (Weither precising my test, weither silencing this type of error BUT I don't want to silence this error for the whole project, I want to silence only on tests file, not on src files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1. You can use [Non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) to assert that `user` is not `null`.

E.g.

`user.ts`:

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const { Schema } = mongoose;

export interface IUser extends mongoose.Document {
  id_test: string;
  password: string;
}

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  id_test: String,
  password: String,
});

const User = mongoose.model<IUser>('User', UserSchema);

export { User };
```

`user.test.ts`:

```js
import { User } from './user';

describe('65148503', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const user = await User.findById('id_test');
    expect(user).toBeDefined();
    expect(user!.password).not.toBe('older_password'); 
  });
});
```

Option 2. Using Option 1, you will use a lot of `!` operators in test cases, if you find it very cumbersome, you can create `tsconfig.json` for the `src` directory with `--strictnullchecks: true`, create `tsconfig.json` for `test` directory with `--strictnullchecks: false`. More info, see [--strictnullchecks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#--strictnullchecks)

E.g.

`tsconfig.json` in the `test` directory:

```json
{
  "extends": "../../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem, but wasn't able to use the non-null assertion as in the accepted answer due to having [no-non-null-assertion](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-non-null-assertion) active as well.

Disabling these rules for tests only was also not appealing.

Instead, I added the following function to my test suite:

```
const assertDefined = <T>(obj: T | null | undefined): T => {
  expect(obj).toBeDefined();
  return obj as T;
}
```

And updated the tests like so:

```
let user = await User.findById("id_test");
user = assertDefined(user);
expect(user.password).not.toBe("older_password");
```

Answer (score 0):

but like, aint you testing ? do not complicate.

```js
import { User } from './user';

describe('65148503', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const user = await User.findById('id_test');
    // if user is null end the test.
    if (!user) {
      throw new Error("User is null");
    }
    // typescript wont b*ch about that any mow!
    expect(user).toBeDefined();
    expect(user!.password).not.toBe('older_password'); 
  });
});
```

Comment: Proposed in this ticket as well: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13652